# Add Day to Timestamp

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp, date-arithmetic

How do I add days to a timestamp?  If my timestamp is `01-JAN-2011 11-09-05` and I add 2 days, I want `03-JAN-2011 11-09-05`.

Answer (score 37):

```
select '01-jan-2011 11-09-05' + interval '2' day
```

Comment: +1. A more complete Oracle example: SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('01-jan-2011 11-09-05','DD-Mon-YYYY HH24-MI-SS') + INTERVAL '2' DAY FROM dual;

Comment: Using interval seems better than using `+` because I noticed loss of timezone with the latter.

Answer (score 4):

A completely Oracle-centric solution is to simply add 2 to the timestamp value as the default interval is days for Oracle dates/timestamps:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('01-jan-2011 11-09-05','DD-Mon-YYYY HH24-MI-SS') + 2
  FROM dual;
```

Comment: a timestamp plus a numeric value yields a date.

Comment: you may lose the timezone by using `+`.

Answer (score 2):

In a similar case, I used:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('01-jan-2011 11-09-05','DD-Mon-YYYY HH24-MI-SS') + NUMTODSINTERVAL(2, 'DAY')
```

Because, othewise, the expression is converted to DATE and precission is lost. See: [NUMTODSINTERVAL documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions103.htm)