# how to get today's date and add 7 days to it and the insert into oracle sql?

Tags: java, date, jdbc

I am working on a program where I want to retrieve today's date in a servlet, then add some days to it say 7 days and then finally insert into oracle SQL database.

I am using prepared statement to do the call. Till now I have the current date using the following code.

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); 
Date date = new Date();
```

How do I add 7 days to it and then insert it in the db?

Comment: Why are you using a `DateFormat` at all? That's only needed if you want to deal with text, and it doesn't look like you need any text here. Now, what exactly do you mean by "7 days"? Do you mean "7 x 24 hours of elapsed time"? Or do you mean "the same time, 7 days later"? Those are different things around DST transitions, assuming you're considering time zones. If you're happy using UTC, it's simpler...

Comment: Basically what i am trying to do is, get the current system date and add 7 days to it.. example todays date 01-05-2015 and make it 08-05-2015 and then insert into db.  I was using date format to achieve this not sure if its the right approach. Any help?

Comment: No, it's not the right approach, because you shouldn't be using *text* for this at all. So you only need the date part, not a date/time - sorry not to have picked up on that before. Now, what time zone are you interested in? It's now May 1st for me, but April 30th for my colleague in California...

Comment: Oh, and which version of Java are you using?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12087419/adding-days-to-a-date-in-java for Date addition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your date format `dd/MM/yyyy`, I'm assuming that you're interested in only date but not date-time (timestamp like dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss), you can do it easily in Java 8 with the new Date Time API in `java.time` package like this

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
date = date.plusDays(7);
```

In your PreparedStatement, you can use setObject like this

```
PreparedStatement ps = Connection.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setObject(2,date); // 2 is the place holder for your date column
```

Note that these new classes are immutable like String, so any change on them will return a new object and you need to capture the return value after calling any method.

For more information, have a look at the API [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html)

Comment: I think this should work for me. Let me check it once.

Comment: Note that this will give you the local date in which your JVM instance is running, you need to consider JonSkeet's advice about considering timezones if you think your application will be running in one location while your users can access it from any location

Comment: A significant thing to consider is the TZ difference between the _JVM and the database_; see my answer for details.

Comment: Yes i considered that but the project i am working on will be running locally on my system. No deployment elsewhere so localtime is good for me.

Comment: The j2ee version in eclipse i am using is not showing the localdate class. Any leads?

Comment: Do you have jdk8 version installed in your system ? If you already hv java8 then you need to map to that jdk in Windows - Preferences - Installed JREs

Answer (score 0):

Get calendar instance, call setTime, call add, call getTime

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#setTime%28java.util.Date%29

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#add%28int,%20int%29

Alternately add the days to your prepared statement ... see [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142916/add-day-to-timestamp) as example

Answer (score 0):

```
       Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
      cal.clear(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
      cal.clear(Calendar.AM_PM);
      cal.clear(Calendar.MINUTE);
      cal.clear(Calendar.SECOND);
      cal.clear(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
    int days = 7;
    // Add days
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, days);
    System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `java.util.Calendar` class Get the days (depends upon your requirement) add desired days to it
Days can be `Day in month or day in week or day in year` I think for your requirement `days in month` is better...

```
java.util.Date date = new Date();
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
//date = cal.getTime();

int days = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, days+7);
date = cal.getTime();
System.out.println(date);
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] your answer to give an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272), because they don't teach the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could let the DB do the arithmetic for you and do this:

```
PreparedStatement ps = null;
try {
    String sql = "INSERT INTO mytable (id, datecolumn) VALUES (?, trunc(?) + 7)";
    ps = myConnection.prepareStatement(sql);
    ps.setString(1, id);
    ps.setDate(2, new Date());
    // if your DB has a different timezone than your app server,
    // you should use this instead
    // ps.setDate(2, new Date(), Calendar.getInstance("<TZ of DB>"));
    ps.executeUpdate();
} finally {
    if (ps != null) {
        ps.close();
    }
}
```

This code inserts a date value to the target column having the time part set to zero (using Oracle's [`trunc` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions201.htm)) and the date incremented by seven days.

It is important to note that if the timezone of your database is different from the JVM's, you should use the [`setDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setDate%28int,%20java.sql.Date,%20java.util.Calendar%29) overload that takes the TZ into account.

Answer (score 0):

For adding let's say 7 days, Following code snippet would work:

```
      Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
     //in below line of code, date is in which which you want to add 7 number of days
        cal.setTime(date);
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 7);
        java.util.Date utilDate = cal.getTime();
        java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());
```

Now you can use sqlDate value in your insert query.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

The modern way is with java.time classes. The Question and other Answers use the troublesome old legacy date-time classes.

## `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
```

Easy to do date math.

```
LocalDate weekLater = today.plusWeeks( 1 );
```

## Database

If you have a database driver compliant with JDBC 4.2 or later, you should be able to pass the `LocalDate` object through JDBC with the `PreparedStatement::setObject` method.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , weekLater );
```

If not, you must convert to the old [`java.sql.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) class.

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf( weekLater );
myPreparedStatement.setDate( … , sqlDate );
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts ***ThreeTen-Backport*** (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).