# How to create update query to set the current date minus few days in the table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to update date in table

Selected data from my_table

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table 
WHERE date_time > to_date('25/01/2017', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
  AND date_time < to_date('15/09/2017', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

Result:

```
  id  | date_time
------+-------------------------------
20873 | 11-SEP-17 02.44.36.953000000 PM
20874 | 14-FEB-17 11.02.32.307000000 AM
20872 | 31-JAN-17 11.50.09.406000000 AM
20871 | 26-JAN-17 12.43.06.868000000 PM
```

Now I want to set the result in date_time column to result - 3 days.

So result after update will be:

```
  id  | date_time
------+-------------------------------
20873 | 08-SEP-17 02.44.36.953000000 PM
20874 | 11-FEB-17 11.02.32.307000000 AM
20872 | 28-JAN-17 11.50.09.406000000 AM
20871 | 23-JAN-17 12.43.06.868000000 PM
```

I am trying something like that:

```
SELECT id, date_time - 3 
FROM my_table 
WHERE date_time > to_date('25/01/2017', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
  AND date_time < to_date('15/09/2017', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

But the result is now without time ...

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? It often does make a difference whether you're using MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL Server or IBM DB2 - or something else even. Please add a relevant tag to your question!

Comment: I am using the SqlDeveloper, so this is Oracle DB

Comment: use `to_date(date_time, 'MM/DD/YYYY')-3`

Comment: this return only the date part of the timestamp column (and updates so) @FrustratedDeveloper .

Comment: use convert function like CONVERT(date_time, ''yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss'')

Comment: `CONVERT()` is not a supported function in Oracle @KiranPatil

Comment: @ Barbaros Özhan I just give idea how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can substract three days by using `interval '-3' day`

```
update my_table t
   set t.date_time = t.date_time + interval '-3' day;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=850fc62430bc0a53094d532dfbc0e236)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
DATEADD(DD, -3,date_time) --FOR MSSQL
TO_DATE(date_time, 'MM/DD/YYYY') -3 --FOR Oracle / PLSQL
```

Try this before you do your update:

```
SELECT id, date_time, TO_DATE(date_time, 'MM/DD/YYYY') -3 as new_date_time
FROM my_table 
WHERE date_time > TO_DATE('25/01/2017', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
AND date_time < TO_DATE('15/09/2017', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

To Update:

```
UPDATE my_table 
SET  date_time = TO_DATE(date_time, 'MM/DD/YYYY') -3
WHERE date_time > TO_DATE('25/01/2017', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
AND date_time < TO_DATE('15/09/2017', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

Comment: I am getting an error: `ORA-00904: "DATEADD": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 30`

Comment: which is the database you have to refer

Comment: Try to use DATEADD(DAY, -3,date_time) instead of DATEADD(DD, -3,date_time)

Comment: @AlexanderS. same problem ... but, check my edited question please

Comment: Sry, Oracle does not support DATEADD(its is MSSQL) use  **to_date(date_time, 'MM/DD/YYYY')-3** like FrustratedDeveloper described.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142916/add-day-to-timestamp

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server, you could use:

`update #my_table
set date_time = dateadd(day, -3, date_time)
;`

I just used #my_table (for temporary table) instead of your my_table. Syntax is different for Teradata but you would need to specifcy required database for specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use Bellow Query..

```
SELECT id, to_char(date_time-3,'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS')
FROM my_table 
WHERE date_time > to_date('25/01/2017', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
  AND date_time < to_date('15/09/2017', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

UPDATE Your table

```
SET  date_time = to_char(date_time-3,'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS')
WHERE date_time > TO_DATE('25/01/2017', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
AND date_time < TO_DATE('15/09/2017', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```